# What is the problem in my code why it can't return long long int value from a function in c

Tags: c, function

```
#include<stdio.h>
int facsum(long long int f)
{
    long long int sum=1,i;
    if(f>0)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=f;i++)
        {
             sum*=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    long long int M,N;
    while(scanf("%lld %lld",&M,&N)!=EOF)
    {
          long long int sum=facsum(M)+facsum(N);
          printf("%lld\n",sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is for https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1161 this problem but i don't know why my code is not returning long long int value.

Comment: What input are you providing for `M` and `N`?  What output are you getting? What output do you ***expect*** to get?

Comment: I would suggest using `uint64_t` from `stdint.h` instead of `long long int`

Comment: It works for me:   Code at: https://ideone.com/GQX5vt  Input `5` and `6`, output `840`.

Comment: Your `facsum()` function is declared to return `int`.  Why would you expect it to be able to return a `long long int`?

Comment: Edit your question to provide a [mre]. That includes an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of the observed output, and a sample of the output desired instead. As it stands, when the source code in the question is compiled and executed and “5 4” is input, then “144” is output, and that seems to be the desired result. So it is not clear what you think the problem is.

Comment: @abelenky The problem is the return value is declared as int, so for small numbers like 5 and 6 it works, but larger ones cause an overflow

Comment: You cannot observe whether your function is returning a `long long int` or not because that is something inside the computer that you cannot see directly. Humans can only see the external behavior of computers or other devices, including output from the program or output from a debugger that is investigating the program. Show actual output that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @anton-tchekov ***I*** know that. ***You*** know that.  My point is to encourage OP to post specific input, and describe expected vs. actual output in a way that illustrates the problem.  Otherwise *"it doesn't work"* is not a useful description.

Answer (score 4):

You declared the function as returning `int`. If you want the return value to be `long long int` declare it as such:

```
long long int facsum(long long int f)   // return type changed HERE
{
    long long int sum=1;
    long long int i;
    if(f>0)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=f;i++)
        {
             sum*=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It is very strange that you used `sum` in your function when it only does multiplication.   This makes it difficult for people to understand your code.

Also, be aware that a `long long int` typically is 64 bits, and the maximum value that will fit in that is about 10^19. 20! is greater than this. So any value of `f` passed to the function greater than 19 will return an incorrect answer.

Answer (score -1):

Sir, inside the while loop you are declaring a new variable each time:

`long long int sum=facsum(M)+facsum(N); // must remove long long int`

As another user mentioned the return type is also an issue, but the main problem is `sum` declaration repeatedly in the while loop

Down below is a working version, please note I used another notation to get `printf` working properly with long long int, I used `%I64d`, that because I am in a windows based system.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

long long int facsum(long long int f)
{
    long long int sum=1,i;
    if(f>0)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=f;i++)
        {
             sum*=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    long long int M,N, sum = 0;
    while(scanf("%lld %lld",&M,&N) == 2) // if get warring or error try %I64d instead %lld
    {
          sum=facsum(M)+facsum(N); // remove long long int
          printf("%lld\n",sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```